# Getting log output from spark workers in google cloud

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, google-cloud-platform, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I am running a spark job in a google cluster and I am trying to acquire some logging information during an RDD map process. Quick example:

```
object LoggerWrapper extends Serializable{
    @transient lazy val logger=Logger.getLogger("myLogger")
}
object Processing{
 ...
    rdd.map(x=>{
       LoggerWrapper.logger.info("processing:"+x)
       foo(x)
    })
   ...
  sparkContext.stop
 }
```

I am following the methodology described [here](https://www.mapr.com/blog/how-log-apache-spark) combined with the directions found [in the Spark webpage](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html). The resulting log4j.properties is the one shown at the end. The file is uploaded using the `--files` flag of the of `gcloud` command (shown below).  I have also updated the yarn-site.xml file so that the property `yarn.log-aggregation-enable` is set to `true`.

My first question is that when I run from the master node `yarn logs -application <applicationID>` I always get the error message "Log aggregation has not completed or is not enabled." Is there anything else that is necessary to be done to collect the messages.

The second question is if it is possible to get the log messages of all workers in the console output as the the process is running. For instance if the spark job is a streaming job, then I would like to get the messages while the job is running.

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/spark.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n

log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.File=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/sparkU.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n


# By default, everything goes to console and file
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, RollingAppender, myConsoleAppender

# My custom logging goes to another file
log4j.logger.myLogger=INFO, RollingAppenderU, myConsoleAppender

# The noisier spark logs go to file only
log4j.logger.spark.storage=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.storage=false
log4j.logger.spark.scheduler=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.scheduler=false
log4j.logger.spark.CacheTracker=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.CacheTracker=false
log4j.logger.spark.CacheTrackerActor=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.CacheTrackerActor=false
log4j.logger.spark.MapOutputTrackerActor=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.MapOutputTrackerActor=false
log4j.logger.spark.MapOutputTracker=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivty.spark.MapOutputTracker=false
```

gcloud command:
`gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster myCluster
--properties spark.driver.memory=1000m,spark.driver.maxResult=512m,spark.executor.memory=1000m --jars gs://path/to/jar/myJar.jar --files /absolute/path/to/local/file/log4j.properties 
--class contextual.wikidata.spark.jobs.$1 <application-arguments>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in the [ContainerManagerImpl](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/b191c6b2021f5c551310b44975b2986dcfb4a405/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/nodemanager/containermanager/ContainerManagerImpl.java#L422), the check for whether log aggregation is enabled is inside nodemanager code:

```
protected LogHandler createLogHandler(Configuration conf, Context context,
    DeletionService deletionService) {
  if (conf.getBoolean(YarnConfiguration.LOG_AGGREGATION_ENABLED,
      YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_LOG_AGGREGATION_ENABLED)) {
    return new LogAggregationService(this.dispatcher, context,
        deletionService, dirsHandler);
  } else {
    return new NonAggregatingLogHandler(this.dispatcher, deletionService,
                                        dirsHandler,
                                        context.getNMStateStore());
  }
}
```

And additionally appears to be done as part of initialization, in creating the `LogHandler` instance for the first time; this means the config value must be provided to all the worker nodes, and must be in the config before the startup/restart of nodemanagers.

In Dataproc, instead of manually modifying the `yarn-site.xml` file yourself, you just use the much easier `--properties` flag when creating your cluster, and the config key will properly get set in all your nodes before daemon services start up:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create my-cluster \
    --properties yarn:yarn.log-aggregation-enable=true
```

Also, you'll need to make sure to run your `yarn logs` command as the same user which ran the jobs or YARN will try to look inside the wrong `$USER` directory in the log aggregation directory:

```
sudo yarn logs -applicationId <applicationId>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Is it possible to read custom logs in a streaming job while the stream processing is still running?

Comment: For now the best way to do that is probably through the [YARN UI](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/concepts/cluster-web-interfaces) and navigating through to container logs directly by clicking through to your running application and finding the links to container logs on the left-hand-side. There are plans for continuing to improve Dataproc's Stackdriver integration in the future where container logs would be accessible through the Cloud Logging UI, but no concrete date yet.